# Is there a way to search questions only or answers only?

Tags: support, questions, answers, search

Is there a way to limit a search to questions only or answers only?

Sometimes I am looking for specific questions, checking for duplicate questions or just simply searching for a problem, not a solution. Other times I might be looking for answers containing certain keywords. Either way there are often many questions/answers in the search results which I am not looking for.

In light of this I think it might be helpful to be able search questions only or answers only, and I would like your opinion on this. Is there a way to do this?

If there isn't a way to do this, is it necessary? Is it plausible?

Comment: Have you looked at the help in the sidebar of the search page?

Comment: `is:q`, `is:a`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Help page for Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) lists a number of operators you can use to make your searches more powerful. Near the bottom, under Miscellaneous operators you'll find `is:question` and `is:answer`, which are fairly self-explanatory. (They can be shortened to a single letter, so `is:q` and `is:a` also work.)

Comment: I've never seen that, even though I have read a lot of the content under `our model`! Thank you.